# Excel 2016 Mac ExportAsFixedFormat to PDF sends to printer

Tags: excel, pdf, printing

I'm writing a macro to manipulate a spreadsheet and save a range of cells as a PDF. Here is the section of code for saving to PDF:

```
    Range("A1:G50").ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      fileName:=myFileName, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

When this runs, it sends the range to my printer...but does NOT save as a PDF.

Anybody else seeing this behavior? What am I doing wrong?